# no match for operator<, even though operator< is defined

Tags: c++

Here is the relevant part of my code. In one source file I have:

```
bool HFolder::operator<(const HFolder &rhs) {
    return name < rhs.name;
}

bool HMessage::operator<(const HMessage &rhs) {
    return contents < rhs.contents;
}


void HMessage::save(const HFolder &f) {
    folders.insert(f);
}
```

I keep getting an error that says "No match for operator< (operand types are 'const HFolder' and 'const HFolder') and it says that the code causing the error is in my save function, where I insert f into the **set** called folders. I get that it needs the < operator so that it can properly sort my set, but I have provided it!

Comment: Add a const at the end of the function signature: `bool HFolder::operator<(const HFolder &rhs) const`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I understand that adding const to the end of the function signature guarantees that the function won't make any changes to its parameters, but why did that work here? Why was it necessary?

Comment: When you mark your function as `const` it will take `this` parameter as a `const HFolder*`. Otherwise it will take `this` parameter as a `HFolder*`. However you cannot initialize a `HFolder*` from a `const HFolder`. Therefore, there isn't a method that suits operand types `const HFolder` and `const HFolder`. You must add `const` to initialize `this` argument as a `const HFolder*` and be able to initialize it from a `const HFolder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your operator as a const-method, like this:

```
bool HFolder::operator<(const HFolder &rhs) const
```

Otherwise it can’t be called on a const-object.